# Getting entire HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the entire HTML of a page, but it seems that the text stops after `</head>`. The following code is essentially how I tested this. What am I doing incorrectly here?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.onload = showHTML();
        function showHTML() {
            html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
            alert(html);
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> This is absolutely useless text. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: declare var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior it's not the problem here. html will be created on the global object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here is a complete working answer... after checking already posted answer I realized it didn't work for multiple reasons..

First you need to put a function in the `onload` event. The `onload` event is written without uppercases.

Also! you need to put the event on the `window` object as such:

```
window.onload = showHTML;
```

Here is a fiddle. Notice on the left that it isn't wrapped inside onload. It's unwrapped in `head` like your code should be.

http://jsfiddle.net/4zsGH/2/

You should have something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = showHTML;
        function showHTML() {
            var html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
            alert(html);
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> This is absolutely useless text. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take off the parenthesis from `document.onLoad = showHTML();`

What's happening is `showHTML()` is being called right away, before the rest of the document is being loaded. Taking off the parenthesis means the function is being set to the `onLoad` callback.

Comment: This does not seem to solve the problem. When I try this solution, it seems that the showHTML() function does not run at all.

Comment: @fakedad try `document.onload` no uppercase letter.

Comment: Changing the case doesn't seem to fix it when the parentheses are absent.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.onload = showHTML;
        function showHTML() {
            var html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
            alert(html);
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> This is absolutely useless text. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When you wrote `document.onLoad = showHTML();` you didn't assign the reference to `showHTML` function to `document.onLoad` but you assigned the value returned by that function i.e. `undefined` (because you called it). I also changed `innerHTML` to `outerHTML`.

Also `document.onload` shouldn't be written in camel case.

Writing `var html = …` isn't essential but it wouldn't run in strict mode. Without it you create a `html` property on global object `window` implicitly.

Comment: Add a description of what you did to fix the problem.

Comment: Removing the parentheses from the function seems to make the function not run at all. Changing to var seems to do nothing. Changing to outerHTML gets me the <html> tags, but it still does not include the body. I've also tried all combinations of each of these fixes, and none seem to work.

Comment: make sure you write `document.onload`, not `document.onLoad`

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
    document.onLoad = showHTML();
    function showHTML() {
       var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
        alert(html);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skhan/4zsGH/

Comment: What your are missing is declare html var.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the fact is that the showHTML is called before the onload event is triggered. You're putting undefined inside onLoad. The fiddle works because the code is wrapped in a onLoad.

Comment: In your fiddle you are executing this script already after the DOM is rendered, and making the same mistake as the OP: assiging the result of showHTML function to document.onload, not the reference to that function.

Comment: Declaring the var does not seem to solve the problem.